# How to use optional Parameter Store parameters in a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation, default-value, aws-parameter-store

I'd like to make CloudFormation look in Parameter Store for a particular parameter - and if not found, look for a different one.

The actual use case is that stacks are deployed for different branches and we'd like to have top-level parameters for all branches that can optionally be overridden by creating a branch-specific parameter. Something like this:

```
dev-param = 120  <-- top-level, applies if branch-specific parameter doesn't exist
dev-param.mybranch = 60  <-- branch-specific parameter
```

Have tried a couple of ways but got an error when deploying the stack for both - see below.

When attempting to use [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html):

```
Parameters: [ssm:dev-param.mybranch] cannot be found.
```

When attempting to use CloudFormation [SSM Parameter Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-ssm-examples).

```
Template format error: Every Default member must be a string.
```

For the latter, the `Default:` field specifies the Parameter Store key name. This needs to be generated dynamically from other CloudFormation parameters, e.g. there is a parameter for the environment type so development key names begin with `dev-` and production keys begin with `prod-`.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).